# Удалился сайт на хостинге

Tags: хостинг

Тут такое дело, что где-то в районе года сайт на хостинге timeweb работал норм, но пару дней как вдруг он удалился у них. Когда я заметил, уже было поздно и бекапы уже удалились. Суть, резервной копии нет, так как никогда бы не подумал, что у популярного хостинга файлы могут просто так удалиться и они просто отмазаться, мол это взлом и мы не причем и помочь не можем. Вопрос: Кто-нибудь сталкивался с такой проблемой и есть какие-нибудь способы вернуть?

Comment: Ну если по договору об оказании услуг Вам действительно ничего не должны, то все что Вы можете сделать, это принять ситуацию как хороший урок и начать все заново

Comment: У всех хостингов и арендуемых серверов есть проблемы. В большинстве случаев они не описаны даже в договоре оферты. Например множество лимитов и всяких подводных камней. Сделать с этим ничего нельзя и требовать что-то бесполезно, будет просто трата нервов. Делайте бэкапы параноидально в несколько мест с большой частотой, тогда будет шанс, что сохранённая копия будет оставать мало от боевого сайта.